# How to keep it a 2D array using filter()?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

May seem silly, but I didn't find anything that wouldn't resort to another function, so...

```
ar1 = [[1, 10, "Item1", 50], [1, 10, "Item1", 50],[1, 10, "Item3", 50]];
```

```
let ar2 = ar1.filter(e => e[2] === "Item1")[0];//To get only of the filtered records
```

It returns:

```
[1, 10, "Item1", 50]
```

but to get it to return:

```
[[1, 10, "Item1", 50]]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Then remove the `[0]` at the end of the `filter()`?

Comment: why not `find` instead?

Comment: @VLAZ, it'll return 2 items, but I need in a 2D array. Thanks!

Comment: Which one do you want then - the first or the second one? You can just `.slice(0, 1)` to get the first, if that's all you want. Or you can use `find()` which returns one item anyway and wrap in in an array.

Comment: Ended up pushing resulting 1D array into an empty one and that does the job. Looks ugly, but got me moving at this point. I'll try the suggestions, as this will prob'bly get closed at any time. Thank you! @VLAZ

Comment: Thanks, @NinaScholz! Had resorted to something ugly, but Cooper gave an answer below and it does exactly what's required!

Comment: Just wrap it in brackets? `let ar2 = [ar1.filter(e => e[2] === "Item1")[0]];` I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
function lfunko() {
  const a = [[1, 10, "Item1", 50], [1, 10, "Item1", 50],[1, 10, "Item3", 50]];
  Logger.log(a.filter(r => r[2] == "Item1").filter((r,i) => i == 1));
}

Execution log
12:42:24 PM Notice  Execution started
12:42:23 PM Info    [[1.0, 10.0, Item1, 50.0]]
12:42:25 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: EXACTLY! I thought that ```map()```would be used for this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `.filter((r,i) => i == 1))`? This is a very ugly way of doing `.slice(1, 2)`